# How to change wallpaper transition speed in Gnome/Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, wallpaper, dconf

I wrote a script that looks like this:

```
import subprocess
import time

while True:
    for i in range(3):
        subprocess.call(["dconf", "write", "/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri", "'file://[my directory]"+str(i)+".png'"])
        time.sleep(.1)
```

Where 0.png, 1.png, and 2.png are pure red, blue, and green images.

Now my goal is to make my desktop background flash like crazy. However, when I run it, Ubuntu insists on slowly fading from one color to another at much longer than 0.1 second speed.

How can I change, or eliminate, the transition speed?

Comment: The proper way to do it is via xml file (see `adwaita-timed.xml`)... [Here's a generator](https://gist.github.com/creature/11101265) you could try (there are several ones if you search the internet). No matter what values you set though it displays each image for at least 1 second.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on how to do it in a good way! I was hoping to get my background to play gifs at full speed, but I guess that might not be possible. Thanks for the advice, though.

Comment: No problem. I don't know if it's a bug or normal behavior... The best place to find out is gnome mailing list (or gnome irc if you use irc...)